# NGINX - No input file specified. - php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

The error is described in the title.
The problem is that it's all ok with .php files, but I can't serve .html files (403 error). `Nginx` and `php-fpm` are working like `www-data` user, owner group for all the site directory is `www-data`, permission for the file I'm testing is 775.

Everything is working fine if I rename `index.html` to `index.php`.

My vhost config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.martynov.test.kooweb.ru martynov.test.kooweb.ru;
    root /home/martynov/www/test.kooweb.ru;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/martynov.test.kooweb.ru.access.log;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|map|coffee|svg)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires max;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
    }

    location ~* \.php {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include common/php-fpm;
    }
}
```

common/php-fpm contains:

```
fastcgi_pass    php-fpm;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_split_path_info                 ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
set             $path_info              $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $path_info;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADMIN            email@example.com;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SIGNATURE        nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_index   index.php;
```

Versions:

- Ubuntu version 16.04
- Nginx version 1.12.1
- Php version 7.1

**UPD**
There are messages which are added to nginx error log:

1. When I'm trying to access `/show5/` address

`[error] 26452#26452: *275 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: <directory>/show5/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: <ip>, server: <server>, request: "GET /show5/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "<domain>"`

2. When I'm trying to access `/show5/index.html` address

`[error] 26452#26452: *278 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '<directory>/show5/index.html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: <ip>, server: <server>, request: "GET /show5/index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "<domain>"`

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: what's in common/php-fpm?

Comment: @gview I've edited the question with `common/php-fpm` data

Comment: Also edited vhost during @gview suggestion, but errors in nginx error.log are the same for both situations.

Comment: Do you have any other server blocks in your config?

Comment: @gview, yes, in separate files

Comment: Perhaps it is entering a different server block.

Comment: @gview, thanks!! There really was an error in another config.
But your answer was very useful too, thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, that was a head scratcher.

Comment: Viktor, it would be helpful to others if you posted your solution—either by answering your own question, or by adding an update to the question to explain what the real problem was and how you fixed it.

Comment: @Kal, I've already accepted an answer below as a solution for my case. Please check if it can resolve your issue too.

Comment: In the comments you said that the accepted answer was helpful but didn't address the 'main problem'. Above, you said there 'was an error in another config', but you didn't say what it was. I just thought it might be helpful for other readers. I'm aware, mind you, that this was 3 years ago and you might not remember the details now! ;-)

Comment: @Kal, oh, yeah, sorry. It was too far away, I just don't remember what the was problem :( I guess there was some another `.conf` file with another `server` block which was handling my requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's clear that you are matching the `.php` location block even in situations when you don't want to be.  I see a couple of things here:

```
 index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

These get tried in order of appearance.  So nginx is going to try a rewrite to /foo/index.php before /foo/index.html.

I would suggest you move index.php to the back of that list.

```
 index index.html index.htm index.php;
```

In your .php location block this is odd:

```
 location ~* \.php {
        try_files $1 $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php    =404;
        include common/php-fpm;
 }
```

You are trying a number of odd things like /foo/bar.php/  and /foo/bar.php/index.php for no apparent reason, considering the location block already entered this location because it matched `something.php`.  I would suggest this be simplified to:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include common/php-fpm;
}
```

Comment: It looks very logical but brings no result :( Errors are the same.

Comment: I've edited my vhosts like this after resolving the main problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a additional block

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Or if you just want it from html files, then add it like below

```
location ~* \.html {
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: There are no any changes in both ways, I still have 403 error. Can I provide any additional info? And of course I made `sudo service nginx restart` every time.

Comment: How you trying to access the file? Post the nginx error logs in your question

Comment: Thanks. I've added this info to the question.